# png image looking very strange

Tags: graphics, floats, pdftex, viewers, png

I'm using latex for years, never seen something like this. The png appears like cut, don't even know how to explain.

This is the original image, I mean how it looks when opened by other app (like preview in macos):

[image]

And this is what I'm getting on the pdf (when openned by preview or skim):

[image]

Interestingly, when I open it in google chrome (also in opera and acrobat reader pro) it looks good.

Not sure if it helps but that image results from a conversion from an hdr image using gdal translate.

Here the code to include the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.png}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any insights on how to proceed?

I guess issue might be related to [OS-dependent, bad rendering when embedding transparent images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313962/os-dependent-bad-rendering-when-embedding-transparent-images?rq=1), because I have different behavior depending on viewer. It might be related to PDFKit?

Related issued being discussed at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283963/gdal-translate-to-png-looking-bad-when-included-in-latex-document.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  I can't reproduce your error. Please add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Your document looks just like the image on my installation, opening the `pdf` with `okular` or `firefox`… Oh, and you shared the imageby embedding it in your post: it is the one at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk3ei.png , right?

Comment: I'm starting to fill its a macOS PDFKit issue only. So u have access to the original image, MD5 (image.png) = b7c6f5dedab89991833f8f5d1a14ada0? (Sorry for the side question)

Comment: I can't reprocue the error with the preview of texmaker, Adobe Reader, Firefox 60 or on other browser. - What happens if you zoom in and out?

Comment: Zoom in/out works normally. Please try with Skim (https://skim-app.sourceforge.io) or TeXShop.